# Application Canadian Work Permit without LMIA

Tags: immigration, canada, work-permit

I have 8 years of IT experience and reside outside of Canada (Indian Nationality). A Canadian company is willing to offer me a job.

Should they require an LMIA to get me to Canada? Are there any options for a work permit visa (preferably open ended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should they require an LMIA to get me to Canada?

In most cases, yes. An LMIA is required for most foreign workers in Canada. Exemptions can be found [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/exemption-codes.html); no obvious situations apply to you.

> Are there any options for a work permit visa(preferably open ended)

For Indian nationals without prior Canadian study or work experiences and who are not family members of a Canadian citizen or (temporary or permanent) resident, the TFW program is essentially the only way for non-immigrant workers. It is in general [not possible](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=177&top=17) to obtain an open work permit before you enter Canada.